# how Nginx proxy works

Tags: nginx, proxy

I'm just curious about how nginx proxy works.

I have two servers, one for frontend and another for storing files.

currently all download links looks like this

```
http://server2.com/examplefile.zip
```

instead if I enable nginx (server 1) to proxy requests to server 2, so the links will look like

```
http://server1.com/proxy/examplefile.zip
```

but if I do that, does both servers consume bandwidth?

if a user downloads a 1 GB file via nginx proxy does both servers consume 1 gb bandwidth or just server 2 consume bandwidth?

Answer (score 1):

This depends on the settings of the servers (e.g. whether things are cached), and their location relative to each other (as well as the traffic accounting used by your hosting provider).