# Angular Container hosted by NGINX Webserver Fails to call a WebApi in another server

Tags: angular, docker, nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-config

**DockerFile of Angular**

```
# stage 1
FROM node:latest as node
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY package.json /usr/src/app
COPY proxy.conf.json /usr/src/app
RUN npm install
COPY . /usr/src/app
#CMD ng serve --host 0.0.0.0
RUN npm run build
#ENTRYPOINT npm proxy

# Stage 2
FROM nginx:1.13.12-alpine

COPY --from=node /usr/src/app/dist/miniRws /usr/share/nginx/html

COPY ./nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
```

**nginx.config**

```
server {
  listen 80;  

  location / {
    root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    index index.html index.htm;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html =404;
  }
}
```

**proxy.config**

```
{
  "/api1": {  
    "target": "http://examwebapicontainer",
    "secure": false,
    "logLevel": "debug",
    "changeOrigin": true
  }
}
```

**package.json** : partial

```
"scripts": {
  "ng": "ng",
  "start": "ng serve --proxy-config proxy.config.json",
  "proxy": "ng serve --proxy-config proxy.conf.json --host 0.0.0.0",
  "build": "ng build"
}
```

I am told we have to somehow add

`proxy_pass http://examwebapicontainer` into the `nginx.conf` file

Can anyone help with editing the configuration files so that I can call the WebApi from the angular container

Comment: Try linking containers: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21553048/linking-containers-in-docker and then use nginx reverse proxy https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20993677/how-nginx-proxy-works